# main_activity.xml content shows front of NavigationDrawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create Navigationdrawer but when i Run the application and drag navigationDrawer
main_activity.xml content gose front of navigationdrawer like blow pictuire.

[image]

This is My main_activity.xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/shark"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


>


<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is drawer_header:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com  /apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/wind_icon"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is drawe_toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"



    />
```

I WANT TO BRING MY NAVIGATIONDRAWER TO FRONT

P.s: main_activity.xml content is more than what i show.rest of it its just some button and text view and etc. that showing front of navigationDrawer

Comment: you mean when u launched the app the drawer is initially opened right?

Comment: No,its work fine.my problem is in that picture.buttun and textxt view and etc.that i created at xml file shows front of drawer as you can see in the picture.how do i fix this?

Comment: make drawerLayout to root layout means instead of constraintlayout use drawerLayout as your root layout

Comment: I did.its messed up all the xml contents

Comment: drawerlayout have only one child. you can use linearlayout in drawerlayout

Comment: i did but its not working either

Comment: refer this site for more info bro i will figured it out https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/navigation-drawer

Comment: Thanks D_K.but i wanna change my strategy and dont use NavigationDrawer.i figured it out that theres is noway to fix this except change my root layout to drawe which if i do that its rouin all my work.Thanks again.

Comment: welcome bro,but sometimes it takes time and little bit logic to figure out.as a developer i wont suggest you to change the strategy if this will solve your problem then ok.but try it Happy coding!!